# How to make menuItem invisible with no id?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to make a menuItem invisible with no id. I have a navigation drawer and it works but don't have a XML file.
Usually you do like this

`MenuItem item = findViewById()`

`item.setVisible(false);`

My code

```
private NavigationItem[] createNavigation(String[] names){
    Log.d(TAG, "createNavigation");
    navItems = new NavigationItem[names.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        Navigation navTo = Navigation.MyPage;
        if(names[i].compareTo(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation)[0]) == 0){
            navTo = Navigation.MyPage;
            if(currentFragment instanceof MyPageFragment)
                navItems[i] = new NavigationItem(names[i], R.drawable.ic_mypage_norm, navTo);
            else
                navItems[i] = new NavigationItem(names[i], R.drawable.ic_mypage_norm, navTo);
        }
        else if(names[i].compareTo(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation)[1]) == 0){
            navTo = Navigation.Book;
            if(currentFragment instanceof BookFragment)
                navItems[i] = new NavigationItem(names[i], R.drawable.ic_book_norm, navTo);
            else
                navItems[i] = new NavigationItem(names[i], R.drawable.ic_book_norm, navTo);
        }
        else if(names[i].compareTo(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation)[2]) == 0){
            navTo = Navigation.Status;
            if(currentFragment instanceof StatusFragment)
                navItems[i] = new NavigationItem(names[i], R.drawable.ic_status_norm, navTo);
            else
                navItems[i] = new NavigationItem(names[i], R.drawable.ic_status_norm, navTo);
        }
        else if(names[i].compareTo(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation)[3]) == 0){
            navTo = Navigation.Information;
            if(currentFragment instanceof InfoFragment)
                navItems[i] = new NavigationItem(names[i], R.drawable.ic_info_norm, navTo);
            else
                navItems[i] = new NavigationItem(names[i], R.drawable.ic_info_norm, navTo);
        }
        else if(names[i].compareTo(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation)[4]) == 0){
            navTo = Navigation.Settings;
            if(currentFragment instanceof SettingsFragment)
                navItems[i] = new NavigationItem(names[i], R.drawable.ic_setting_norm, navTo);
            else
                navItems[i] = new NavigationItem(names[i], R.drawable.ic_setting_norm, navTo);
        }

        else if(names[i].compareTo(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation)[5]) == 0){
            navTo = Navigation.PanoramaHome;
            if(currentFragment instanceof PanoramaHomeFragment){
                navItems[i] = new NavigationItem(names[i], R.drawable.ic_setting_norm, navTo);
                Log.d(TAG, "createNavigation: if");
            }
            else
                navItems[i] = new NavigationItem(names[i], R.drawable.ic_setting_norm, navTo);
                Log.d(TAG, "createNavigation: else");
        }
        //navItems[i] = new NavigationItem(names[i], R.drawable.pholder_icon, navTo);
    }
    return navItems;
}

void navigateTo(NavigationItem ni){
    Log.d(TAG, "navigateTo");
    Fragment newFragment = null;
    String fragTag = null;
    if(ni.isMyPage()){
        fragTag = getString(R.string.mypage);
        newFragment = fragMan.findFragmentByTag(fragTag);
        if(newFragment == null)
            newFragment = new MyPageFragment();
    }
    else if(ni.isBooking()){
        fragTag = getString(R.string.booking);
        newFragment = fragMan.findFragmentByTag(fragTag);
        if(newFragment == null)
            newFragment = new BookFragment();
    }
    else if(ni.isStatus()){
        fragTag = getString(R.string.status);
        newFragment = fragMan.findFragmentByTag(fragTag);
        if(newFragment == null)
            newFragment = new StatusFragment();
    }
    else if(ni.isInfo()){
        fragTag = getString(R.string.info);
        newFragment = fragMan.findFragmentByTag(fragTag);
        if(newFragment == null)
            newFragment = new InfoFragment();
    }
    else if(ni.isSettings()){
        fragTag = getString(R.string.settings);
        newFragment = fragMan.findFragmentByTag(fragTag);
        if(newFragment == null)
            newFragment = new SettingsFragment();
    }
    //TODO CHANGE TO PANORAMA HOME Fragment.
    else if(ni.isPanoramaHome()){
        fragTag = getString(R.string.panorama_home);
        newFragment = fragMan.findFragmentByTag(fragTag);
        if(newFragment == null)
            newFragment = new PanoramaHomeFragment();
    }

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    currentFragment = newFragment;
    transaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment, newFragment, fragTag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.commit();
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    navDrawerSetup();
    setLoading(false);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu");
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    if(currentFragment != null){
        if(currentFragment instanceof BookFragment){
            CacheController ch = new CacheController(this);
            ch.openDatabases();
            if(ch.getAvailableLocalPreChoices() != 1)
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.bookmenu, menu);
            ch.closeDatabases();
        }
        else if(currentFragment instanceof StatusFragment || currentFragment instanceof InfoFragment || currentFragment instanceof MyPageFragment){
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.refreshmenu, menu);
        }
        else{
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.nomenu, menu);
        }
        //need id for the fragment to work.
        //MenuItem item = findViewById()
        //item.setVisible(false);

        MenuItem m = menu.getItem(1);
        m.setVisible(false);
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Show full code.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the visibility of a menu item using the position:-

```
  MenuItem m = menu.getItem(2);
  m.setVisible(false);
```

I hope this will work for you @silversoul

Comment: Hi! I did try it. However I always get a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException. Still thank you for answering :)